# Jquery appending value of html to input box but not text within a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have an ajax query that brings back a searched name and id:

```
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    extract($row);
    echo "<li>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."<span class='uid'>".$row['user_id']."</span></li>";
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is append the first and last names to a search box and then retrieve the userid and place that in another search box.

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('.client_name').not('span.uid').val($(this).text());
    $('.listbox').hide();
    });
```

The above jquery does not work as I feel I am using the 'not' property wrongly. Is it possible to split these values ?

html is as follows

```
<div class="form_align">
        <label>
        Client Name
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="client_name" />

        <label>
        Client Account No.
        <span class="small">This is important !</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="client_account_no" />
        <div class="listbox">
            <div class="nameslist">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is `.client_name`? Your AJAX response does not include that class.

Comment: Please post more of the surrounding HTML markup, which receives the `<li>` from your AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry - .client_name is the class of the input box where the text needs to goto

Comment: First and last names into .client_name  and then I need to get the text within the span to the next input box .client_account_no

Comment: Ok I think I get it - see below.

Comment: `$('.client_name').not('span.uid')` ... the `not` makes little sense since an `input` can't be a `span`. Would still find the `input` but the `not` is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend changing the AJAX response to surround the names in their own `<span class='ajaxname'>`. That will make it a lot simpler to target the name separately from the sibling node `<span class='uid'>`.  Otherwise, to exclude the value of the `<span class='uid'>` you would need to do something tricky like temporarily remove it from the DOM to get the `<li>`'s text then place it back in. All way too complicated.

```
echo "<li><span class='ajaxname'>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</span><span class='uid'>".$row['user_id']."</span></li>";
```

Since the AJAX response sends a new `<li>` into your DOM, you will need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the click event.

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    // Get the name from its <span> and put it into the input
    $('.client_name').val($(this).find('.ajaxname').text());
    // Get the uid and put it inot .client_account_no
    $('.client_account_name').val($(this).find('.uid').text());
    $('.listbox').hide();
});
```

And what do you know, [*it works* (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Ecmvd/).

#### Addendum:

Other answer never materialized, so here is an arguably better solution using a `data-uid` attribute in the AJAX-returned HTML

```
// PHP supplies the user_id in an HTML attribute data-uid
echo "<li data-uid='" . $row['user_id'] . "'>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'] . "</li>";
```

The JavaScript has a much easier job then:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    // Get the name, which is just the <li>'s text content...
    $('.client_name').val($(this).text());
    // Get the uid from the data-uid attribute
    $('.client_account_name').val($(this).attr('data-uid'));
    $('.listbox').hide();
});
```

Comment: `data-` attributes would also make it simple

Comment: @charlietfl Yes they would. You should contribute an answer and I'll +1 it.